# How to bind a Razor Pages checkbox click event to server-side code

Tags: razor, razor-pages

I have a list of items on a Razor page, each with a checkbox. I want that when ticking or unticking a checkbox, the information is sent to the service behind that page, and then the list is updated with a time when the new setting took place.

It's not a button, it's a checkbox, so I am not sure how to use `<form>` in this case. And it'd be nicer if a waiting icon could spin while the operation was ongoing.

What can I use? Is it possible to have a method on my `PageModel` class which does this operation?

Comment: Use AJAX to make an asynchronous request to the server: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And I guess I can use `?handler=Xxx` to get to a dedicated method `OnGetXxx` on my page. Will try to put this all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to summarize my findings.

1. Create a handler method on the page, called e.g. `OnPostMyAction`. Take in the needed arguments.

```cs
// itemId can also be Guid
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostMyAction(long itemId, bool isEnabled)
{
    await mRepository.EnableItem(itemId, isEnabled);

    return new OkResult();
}
```

2. Create a JS function in the `Scripts` section of the page.

```js
function requestMyAction(itemId, isChecked, loaderId) {
    document.getElementById(loaderId).style.display = "inline-block";
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            document.getElementById(loaderId).style.display = "none";
            if (this.status === 200) {
                // Ok
            }
        }
    };
    var url = '@Url.Page("/PageName", "MyAction")';
    xhr.open('POST', url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('RequestVerificationToken', '@Xsrf.GetAndStoreTokens(Model.HttpContext).RequestToken');
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('itemId', itemId);
    data.append('isEnabled', isChecked);
    xhr.send(data);
}
```

I know that there exists a `fetch` API, maybe someone can write a new implementation here :-)  I am not experienced in JS, so I took what I found in a more-or-less implemented state.

3. Inject the antiforgery mechanism at the start of the page.

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery Xsrf
```

4. Add a `loader` class in CSS:

```css
.loader {
    border: 6px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
    border-top: 6px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    animation: loaderSpin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes loaderSpin {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

5. Add a click handler and a `loader` element (possibly next to the checkbox).

```
<input asp-for="@item.IsEnabled"
    onclick="requestMyAction('@item.Id', this.checked, 'loader-@item.Id');" />
<div class="loader" style="display: none;" id="loader-@item.Id"></div>
```